# On a branch.. how to find at which commit things broke?

Tags: git, version-control

I have a branch say `release-branch`.
Different team members have their own branches say:

Team member 1 has `tm1-branch`

Team member 2 has `tm2-branch`
.
.
and so on.

After the PRs (Pull Requests) are created and merged into `release-branch`. For example, I see following listing when I goto commits for that branch.

Author--- Commit -- Message

---

TM1---- CommitHash1 --- Commit message

TM2---- CommitHash2 --- Commit message

TM1---- CommitHash3 [M]--- Commit message -- This one is for PR merge

TM3---- CommitHash4 --- Commit message

TM2---- CommitHash5 --- Commit message

TM2---- CommitHash6[M] --- Commit message -- This one is for PR merge

TM1---- CommitHash7 --- Commit message

What I need to find out.. is at which commit things broke on this branch.
I tried checkout from the commit hashes (merged PR ones) and verify.
Things work fine say at `CommitHash6` and break at `CommitHash3`.

Now how do I find what commit or change broke things?

Comment: Try [`git-bisect`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect).

Comment: What do you mean by broke? Code being deleted, something missing, code does not compile and you don't know why... If you don't know why it broke, I don't think you have more options than checkout different commits of the branch and test them one by one (or with a script). If you know the cause, you can look for deleted code, for instance with `git log -S "code that is missing" ./file/containing/the/code`